# Crystal Reports Crosstab Suppress subtotals when there is one row

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am using a crosstab in crystal reports that has 3 grouping levels this can create a lot of subtotals across the rows. Often the subtotal row is useless if there is only one row it is summing from. Is it possible to supress subtotals where there is only one row of data? Leaving the useful subtotals (I know I can suppress the lot).

Illustration below this is how I currently have it:

[image: Current CrossTab]

This is how I would like it to be:

[image: Wanted CrossTab]

Notice the sub totals for the Middle Grouping B and T have been removed leaving just C as it has two distinct rows below it. To me that looks much cleared and I would be surprised if this can't be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend skipping the Crystal Crosstab and making your own:

1. Make a subreport where you want the crosstab to appear (you may not need a subreport, but I'll assume you do).
2. Group the subreport by your 3 levels.
3. Drag & drop your fields onto your design however you want them.
4. In the group footer sections, add some custom field formulas with the `sum({number},{group})` for the custom formula.
5. Using the section expert, suppress the fields as you see fit. The `count({number},{group})` would be useful here.

It'll take a fair bit of tweaking to get it right, and of course the columns in your manual crosstab will be fixed, but this allows for the most customization.

Comment: Thanks I had thought about that but obviously it is a lot of work. I hoped someone knew an easy way with a suppression formula or similar.